# Volume of a solid rotated around axis

Tags: calculus, volume

The task is finding the volume of the solid found by rotating $$ x=2y-y^2$$

From $$x=0$$

around the axis $$y=-1$$

Comment: $\dfrac{16\pi}3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to evaluate such volume we use the [Pappus's centroid theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem).

We rotate the plane region 
$$A:=\{(x,y): y\in [0,2], 0\leq x\leq y(2-y)\}$$
around the line $y=-1$. 
By symmetry the centre of mass of $A$ is along the line $y=1$ and therefore its distance from the axis $y=-1$ is $r=1-(-1)=2$.

Hence the volume is
$$V= 2\pi\cdot r\cdot|A|=\frac{16\pi}{3}$$
where $|A|$ is the area of $A$, that is
$$|A|=\int_{y=0}^2 (2y-y^2) dy=\left[y^2-\frac{y^3}{3}\right]_0^2=\frac{4}{3}.$$

P.S. By using the [disc formula](http://Disc%20integration) you should evaluate
$$\pi\int_{x=0}^!\left((2+\sqrt{1-x})^2-(2-\sqrt{1-x})^2\right)dx=\frac{16\pi}{3}.$$

Comment: Thank you, couldn't find a way to do this with disk or shell formulas.

Comment: @George Rosager See my P.S. and fill the details.

Comment: I made the mistake by thinking that you couldnt express y as a function of x, I dont know why I thought that,  thats why I couldnt get the disk formula to work. Now it all makes sense, thank you.

Comment: Yup, I know, just forgot :)